# jmeter non-GUI console Summary report config

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When I use the jmeter non-gui mode test to get the results in the console, but these parameters are not enough, I would like to know how to add the parameters I want such as: Aggregation report "99% Line", so that this parameter is also shown in the control Table summary, do not know how to operate

[image]

Comment: By default, you get min, max, avg, error and summary. You can configure the Summarizer in `jmeter.properties`. Search for 'summariser' to enable the properties.

Comment: @ NaveenKumar Namachivayam Jmeter.properties file can not modify the display, see the current situation can only modify the relevant source code, like the answer given below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into [Summariser class source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/Summariser.java) currently there is no configuration option which you could turn on, if you need it you will have to patch the aforementioned class and re-compile JMeter (or create your own summary reporter, see [How to Write a plugin for JMeter for details](https://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf))

---

As a workaround you might want to run your JMeter test via [Taurus tool](http://gettaurus.org/), it is 100% JMeter compatible as it uses JMeter under the hood and you will get some nice features on top, for example quantiles reporting

[image: Taurus quantiles reporting]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try to modify the relevant source code！